# Как вычислить полигоны модели попадающие во фрустум (прямоугольник)?

Tags: java, opengl, геометрия, lwjgl, вычислительная-геометрия

Есть сцена, на сцене obj модель. Требуется выделить полигоны модели.

Нажимается правая кнопка мыши далее вокруг нажатой точки рисуется прямоугольник, на углах прямоугольника рисуется селектирующие лучи. И нужно выделить(закрасить цветом) те треугольники из модели, которые попали в эту область.

Использую LWJGL и библиотеку JOML. Я нашел такие функции как: `unproject` , которая из экранных координат переводит в мировые и `intersectRayPlane` - пересекает ли луч полигон.

Cделал селектирующие лучи( получилось 6 плоскостей) . необходимо теперь закрасить цветом треугольники, которые находятся внутри этой усеченной пирамиды. Как посоветуете это сделать? Подскажите не геометрию, а именно как это программно сделать в шейдере. Дано: матрица P, матрица вьюхи, матрица Q=PV, матрица модели M, координаты вершин плоскостей (их 8 есть origin(координата конца луча) и dir(не знаю что это означает использовал функцию unproject)),координаты вершин модели и его нормали.

Я нашел компоненты **a b c d** всех 6 плоскостей фрустума.  Далее я беру точку и меряю расстоянию до каждой из 6 плоскостей фрустума. Если расстояние отрицательное, значит точка не находится внутри фрустума. Ниже шейдеры в них скорее всего и ошибка: 
В вершинный шейдер передаю

```
 vec4[6] planes - a b c d для 6 плоскостей.
out float[6] dis;- это расстояния, которые я передаю во фрагментный шейдер
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out float[6] dis;
out vec3 normal_modelspace;
out vec3 vertex_modelspace;
out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 vertexColor;
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;

uniform vec4[6] planes;


void main() {
    TexCoord = texCoord;
    vertex_modelspace = (M * vec4(vertexPos.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
    vertexColor = vec4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = P * V * vec4(vertex_modelspace.xyz, 1.0);
    normal_modelspace = (M * vec4(normal.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
    vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace = vec3(0,0,0) - (V * M * vec4(vertexPos,1)).xyz;

     for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
       float denom = sqrt(planes[0].x * planes[0].x + planes[0].y * planes[0].y + planes[0].z * planes[0].z);
       dis[i] = float((planes[0].x * vertex_modelspace.x + planes[0].y * vertex_modelspace.y + planes[0].z * vertex_modelspace.z + planes[0].w) / denom);
     }
}
```

**Фрагментный шейдер** 
здесь я в цикле проверяю расстояния для точки, если найдено отрицательное значение, то должно закрашиваться цветом.

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 normal_modelspace;
in vec3 vertex_modelspace;
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec4 vertexColor;
in float[6] dis;
out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 light_worldspace;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main() {
  vec3 n = normalize(normal_modelspace);
  vec3 l = normalize(light_worldspace - vertex_modelspace);
  float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n, l), 0,1 );
  float ambient = 0.05;
    int i=0;
    while(i<6 && dis[i]<=0){
      i++;
    }
    if(i==6){
      color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
    }
    else
      color = vertexColor;
}
```

[image: результат]

Comment: Уточните, для чего требуется выделять полигоны модели, если только для подсветки, то можно в шейдере написать выбор цвета в зависимости от попадания фрагмента в объем прямоугольника.

Comment: @Kromster просто закрасить любым цветом и как сделать эти селектирующие лучи ?

Comment: Версия lwjgl 3.x то есть lwjgl.util в этой версии нет

Comment: "углах прямоугольника рисуется селектирующие лучи" - уточните, куда эти лучи направлены?

Comment: @Kromster Для выделения объектов одиночным щелчком мыши необходимо построить луч, выходящий из точки, в которую пользователь навёл указатель мыши в направлении оси z и проверить, пересекается ли этот луч с полигонами на сцене.

Comment: Путанно выходит. Перепишите условия в вопросе поточнее. А то то выделение объектов, то треугольников. То 1 луч, то прямоугольник с лучами. То по мировой оси Z, то по оси Z камеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наивный алгоритм (без оптимизаций), будет примерно таким:

1. Определить ограничивающий объем в мировых координатах (усеченную пирамиду, т.н. фрустум). Можно задать его в виде 6 плоскостей (т.е. по плоскости на каждую грань), заданных в виде нормаль (обозначает куда плоскость "смотрит") и расстояние (от мирового центра координат).
2. Преобразовать модель в мировые координаты (или наоборот привести фрустум к координатам модели)
3. Для каждого полигона в модели проверить все его вершины:
4. Для каждой вершины проверить ее расположение относительно каждой из 6 ограничивающих плоскостей. Код проверки (на Delphi, но суть та же)

   ```
   Result := True; // т.е. точка с той же стороны, куда "смотрит" нормаль
   for I := 0 to 5 do
   begin
     d :=  Planes[I].Normal.X * aPoint.X +
         Planes[I].Normal.Y * aPoint.Y +
         Planes[I].Normal.Z * aPoint.Z +
         Planes[I].Distance;

     if d <= 0 then Exit(False);
   end;
   ```

Если для всех плоскостей все точки полигона "внутри", то и полигон считается "внутри" фрустума.

P.S. Если что-то уточнить - задавайте вопросы в комментариях.

Comment: не подскажите в чем проблема у меня, обновил вопрос